# How to allow all people to access mysql database?

Tags: mysql

How can I set to allow all the people to access mysql databases??I mean like how to set wildcard so that anyone can access mysql databases.

Comment: What type of access do you want to allow? By default, mysql requires a user account/password for access. You can create a user account with very limited permissions (read-only) through PHPMyAdmin (which from your other posts I know you are running). Granting unrestricted access is a major security hole.

Comment: I want to access my server's databases by a program which is on other's computers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your comments, you want to access from another computer. This can be done the following way:

1. In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

uncomment bind-address

```
# bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

Restart mysql:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Now you can add a new user (for example with phpmyadmin) an restrict the connection to the ip of the other computer.

**You can add a user without IP-Restriction but this is highly insecure!**

Comment: So you could accept the answer. [What should I do when my question is answered](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)